# Simple Webservice with JSON / Heroku / MongoDB

Tags: web-services, mongodb, heroku

I want to create a simple webservice that can accept JSON Data and store that data. I have about 50 users so the dataload will never be really high. I think I would be ok with one dyno, which is the free pricing model.

Having searched around the net, I think heroku and mongoDb is what I should use. Since I've never used any of those I would like to get some feedback if this is the right choice or if its even possible in the way I want to use it.

The service would just receive small & simple JSON objects and store them. Later on I would retreive and delete them.

iOS App has JSON Data -> sends that data to my service. -> my service stores the data. -> I fetch the data and delete the data.

Am I on the right track ?? I have done little/to no web communication regarding iPhone, so bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very easily with Rails and a Postgres backend, and of course it could be housed on Heroku.

It's as simple as running a scaffold builder for each class you need:

```
$rails generate scaffold YourClass attribute1:string attribute2:integer attribute3:boolean
$rake db:migrate
```

Push to Heroku and you will be able to access JSON by appending .json to the page name. For example if your site is called **shining-guitar-311.herokuapp.com**, then the index page will be **shining-guitar-311.herokuapp.com/your_classes.html**.

To bring the page down as JSON you would access: 
**shining-guitar-311.herokuapp.com/your_classes.json**

It really is as simple as that if you go with Rails defaults. You may want to apply some security also or create additional classes, but that will get you started.

Heroku have a good article on publishing Rails apps to their infrastructure:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3